# Listing rideshare as a job

Tags: applications

I drive for both Uber and Lyft in my free time. I am in need of listing my previous employers for a job application. It is a teaching job, but the job application doesn’t say to list last 3 teaching jobs, it just says to list last three employers. I would like to list at least one of them- Uber or Lyft- as a previous employer. Would this be ok to do? I understand I’m an independent contractor/ self- employed with Uber and Lyft but just curious if this would be ok to do.

Comment: It's arguable (and Uber frequently argues it) that Uber and Lyft are not employers. If you didn't want to list them you could make that argument.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where you are based, but I don't see why you coudn't put that you worked for these companies. Is there something that i'm missing here? Clearly these jobs won't speak to your teaching abilities but will speak to your commitment and determination. Hope this helps. T

Comment: Aren't the Uber and Lyft drivers technically not employed by them but are contractors who chose to work with Uber and Lyft?

Comment: @joelfischerr This depends on region currently. In the UK, Uber lost their case to label workers "self-employed" as they regulate the work in a similar fashion to a real employer. But you're definitely correct that the default is to be considered self-employed by Uber, except in regions they've been legally forced not to.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to list at least one of them- Uber or Lyft- as a previous
>   employer. Would this be ok to do? I understand I’m an independent
>   contractor/ self- employed with Uber and Lyft but just curious if this
>   would be ok to do.

Normally you would want to list three jobs that would show you in the best light as regards a teaching position. I don't see how ridesharing positions would help in that.

But if those are the only positions you've held, or if you don't have anything better to offer, it would likely be fine.